# Acknowledging someone had an impact on your choice of career

Tags: phrase-request, style, register

In the acknowledgements section of my thesis, I just wrote:

> I would like to thank my supervisor X [...]. To a large extent, it is to his credit that I found my way into the field of Y and I am very grateful for it.

`It is to his credit` does not sound right to me, but I cannot seem to find a better expression. What I am trying to say is that he is responsible for me getting into the field, or that it is his fault - but it should sound much more positive of course.

**Is there a better phrase for what I am trying to say?**

Comment: "It is because of him that I found...." ??

Comment: @CinCout Thanks! Yes, that would be an option, but it sounds a bit too pedestrian in my ears. I'd like to emphasize that he deserves credit for this. If it's the only suitable phrase I'll take it though.

Comment: *because of him*, *because of his guidance, encouragement, etc*. But "to a large extent it is to his credit that" is verbose.

Comment: @TRomano Is it only verbose or is it wrong, in your opinion?

Comment: It is only "wrong" in the sense that there is a humorous suggestion that it was partly to his discredit.

Comment: @TRomano I see, thanks. What I would like to imply is that other people have also helped. Could you perhaps help me get rid of the humour in it?

Comment: "because of him" or "thanks to him" are colloquial but not "pedestrian", whereas "to a large extent it is to his credit that" has trouble crossing the street.

Comment: @TRomano Thanks. Please feel free to turn your comments into an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many ways to express this, but to focus on the ways that use the words and expressions in your example:

"To a large extent" is fine.  It's a standard idiom that means "mostly" and works in this context.

However, "to his credit" seems a bit off.  I *credit* someone with something positive, for example:

> I credit him with helping me invent the rotary engine.

But "to his credit" describes a positive attribute or action of that person, and not necessarily what he has accomplished for someone else.  It's also often used as an excuse for some other, less positive attribute:

> He's not a good speaker, but to his credit, he always speaks the truth.

So in this context I would say something like:

> I would like to thank my supervisor, Mr. Rogers.  To a large extent I credit him with helping me find my way into the field of theoretical physics.

"I am very grateful for it" is fine but awkward.  You can say instead, "for which I am very grateful".   The reason I say *awkward* is because it's not clear what the pronoun "it" refers to.  If you like you can state it explicitly:

> I am very grateful for his help.

Other ways to express the same sentiment:

> I would like to thank Bob Marley.  For the most part, it was due to his encouragement that I got into the music industry and I owe him a debt of gratitude.
>
> I would like to thank Arnold Schwarzenegger.  It was largely because of his example that I chose to become a professional bodybuilder, and for that I am very grateful.
>
> I would like to thank the Queen of England, without whose inspiration and advocacy I would never have been able to become monarch of my own country.  For this I owe her eternal thanks.

Comment: Why do you say "whose" not "her"  please ?

Comment: I'm not sure of the exact grammar term for it, but it's the pronoun in the subordinate phrase that refers back to "the Queen".  If I was starting a new sentence I would use "Her" instead.

Comment: _"It's also often used as an excuse for some other, less positive attribute"_ - I have suspected as much - thanks for clearing this up, and for the useful examples.

Comment: @MathiasMüller You are welcome.  I added a bit more to my answer to clarify a few points.

Answer (score 3):

Original:

> I would like to thank my supervisor X [...]. To a large extent, it is to his credit that I found my way into the field of Y and I am very grateful for it.

Revision:

> I would like to thank my supervisor X [...]. To a large extent, it is **due to his mentoring** that I found my way into the field of Y and I am very grateful for **his encouragement**.

Not sure this is better, but it is what I would say.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have accepted Andrew's answer because it is more comprehensive.

Comment: This is not a contest and I am happy you found what works for you!

Answer (score -2):

Desiring to express how thankful you are for someone who helped  you get into your field. Here are some examples:

> I would like to thank my supervisor X [...]. To a large extent for
>   helping me find my way into the field of Y and I am very grateful for
>   it.
>
> I would like to thank my supervisor X [...]. To a large extent, who helped 
>   me find my way into the field of Y and I
>   am very grateful for it.

Or, simply:

> I would like to thank my supervisor X [...]. To a large extent to
>   him for having helped me find my way into the field of Y and I am very grateful
>   for it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm not sure your suggestions go well together with "to a large extent", e.g. I don't think being "thankful to a large extent" is a valid phrase, is it? I am not sure whether "all merits go to someone" is a phrase either, where did you find it?

Comment: Oh, I thought there was an end point after "extent". Haha, sorry, I will edit it in order to adapt it to the: To a large extent.

Oh, yes, it's a phrase, it is most likely used in army contexts, the word 'merit' is hardly used in daily speeches.

Comment: I am sorry but your examples still seem odd, I know for a fact that they are not fluent English sentences. Using the phrase "help/helping" is a good suggestion though.